# JButtons not being resized when resizing window

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am creating a virtual keyboard for a hangman game and trying to set it so the width of the buttons are adjusted when the window is resized. Right now when I start the program I can't see all of the the buttons - I need to resize the width of the window so I can see all of them.

I have tried to use `button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35, 35));` on the buttons and while this does size the buttons properly, when I start the program there is a 2 second delay before any buttons appear on screen. I have commented where this line is in `createKeyboard()`

How do I squash the buttons (keeping them in the same order) when the window is resized? Alternatively, is there any way to use `setPreferredSize` without causing the delay?

```
public GUI() {
    createWindow();
    createPanels();
    addPanels();
    createKeyboard();
    setMainFrameVisible();
}

public void createWindow() {
    mainFrame = new JFrame();
    mainFrame.setSize(500, 300); //500, 300
    mainFrame.setTitle("Hangman");
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void createPanels() {
    pnlMain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    pnlKeyboard = new JPanel(new GridLayout (4, 1)); 
    pnlKeyboardQP = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    pnlKeyboardAL = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    pnlKeyboardZM = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
}

public void addPanels() {
    mainFrame.add(pnlMain);
    pnlMain.add(pnlKeyboard, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pnlKeyboard.add(pnlKeyboardQP);
    pnlKeyboard.add(pnlKeyboardAL);
    pnlKeyboard.add(pnlKeyboardZM);

}

public void createKeyboard() {
    String keyboardFormat = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
    String buttonLabel;
    char buttonLabelChar;

    for (int i = 0; i < keyboardFormat.length(); i ++) {    
        buttonLabelChar = keyboardFormat.charAt(i);
        buttonLabel = "" + buttonLabelChar; 
        JButton button = new JButton(buttonLabel);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35, 35)); // This is causing 2 second delay when game started
        button.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("Button pressed");
                }
            }
        );
        addKeyboard(buttonLabelChar, button); 
    }
}


public void addKeyboard(char c, JButton button) {

    String QP = "QWERTYUIOP";
    String AL = "ASDFGHJKL";
    String ZM = "ZXCVBNM";

    if (QP.indexOf(c) >= 0) {
        pnlKeyboardQP.add(button);
    }
    else if (AL.indexOf(c) >= 0) {
        pnlKeyboardAL.add(button);
    }
    else if (ZM.indexOf(c) >= 0) {
        pnlKeyboardZM.add(button);
    }
```

Comment: The setPreferredSize() method will not cause a 2 second delay. The components don't change size because you are using a FlowLayout and FlowLayout always respects the size of the component. Maybe you want a GridLayout. The buttons will be resized to the same size and take up all the space available.

Comment: @camickr Thanks GridLayout does work, but because there are a different number of buttons in each row some rows end up having larger buttons than others.

Comment: you could use components to fill the empty space, like an empty JLabel would do, or use a different layout manager

Comment: @Ansharja Thanks for the suggestion I did consider this but wasn't sure if it would be considered best practice.

Comment: @jb2003 Maybe another layout manager could be a best solution, but i've seen other answers on this site where that solution (using empty labels) was suggested as well.